# random.choice() not selecting all possibilities

Tags: python, function, random

`random.choice()` in Python does not work correctly.

I have the following function, but the following happens when called:

```
def Randomswitch():
    thechosenone = random.choice(range(0, 2))
    if (thechosenone == 0):
        return "WIN"
    if (thechosenone == 1):
        return "LOSE"

Randomswitch()
```

When `Randomswitch` is called it only returns `WIN` every time it's called.

I am breaking my head trying to figure this out.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behaviour. When [I run this](https://replit.com/@trincottrincots/httpsstackoverflowcomq702338255459839), I get both WIN and LOSE.

Comment: Possibilities: you're running different code from what you posted, `random` isn't the stdlib `random` module, or you called `random.seed` without understanding the implications.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Seems to be working pretty well, have you tried only a few times? Let's try 10,000 times and count the occurrences:

```
import random
from collections import Counter

def Randomswitch():
    thechosenone = random.choice(range(0, 2))
    if (thechosenone == 0):
        return "WIN"
    if (thechosenone == 1):
        return "LOSE"

Counter(Randomswitch() for i in range(10000))
```

output:

```
Counter({'LOSE': 4980, 'WIN': 5020})
```

Seems pretty decent ;)

##### improving the code

That said, you code can be improved, why don't you just pass the values to chose from to `random.choice`?

```
def Randomswitch():
    return random.choice(['WIN', 'LOSE'])
```

Comment: *"Seems to be working pretty well"*: there is a closure reason for this: "not reproducible".

Comment: @trincot Sure, this was more of a polite phrasing ;) regarding closing the question, feel free to vote for it, I often do it myself. Felt more like trying to provide an explanation here. It seems like random numbers are sometimes magic for beginners and they expect to have a change every other time.

Comment: Don't answer such questions. Place a comment instead and vote to close.

Answer (score -2):

try this:

```
import random

def Randomswitch():
    range_list = [i for i in range(0, 2)]
    thechosenone = random.choice(range_list)
    if (thechosenone == 0):
        return "WIN"
    if (thechosenone == 1):
        return "LOSE"
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining _how_ it works and _when_ to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Comment: Even more, it should explain what the problem was.

Comment: it's better to explain the problem more specifically, I've tried this code and it has returned "LOSE" multiple times!

Answer (score -3):

Try use `random.randint(0,1)` instead of `random.choice(range(0,2))`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining _how_ it works and _when_ to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Comment: Even more, it should explain what the problem was.